# multiple instances of a directive that uses controller - multiple instances of a controller?

Tags: angularjs

If I have a directive that uses a controller:

```
angular.module("module")
  .controller("fooController", ["$scope", function($scope) {
    ...
  })
  .directive("foo", function() {
    return {
      restrict: "E",
      controller: "fooController",
      link: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
        // Do some things with the scope of the controller here
      }
    }
  })
```

And multiple instances of that directive:

```
<foo></foo>
<foo></foo>
```

1. How many instances of the controller will be created?
2. Does it depend on whether the directive defines new child or isolated scope?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One controller instance will be created for each `<foo>` element defined in the DOM. So in the example given, there will be 2 controller instances created.

This does not depend on whether the directive defines a new child or isolated scope.